# Best Way to call WebAPI endpoint for child entity from Mobile and Web

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint, webapi

There are two tables **Item** and **ItemExtras** both have similar table structure in database.
We have two price fields in UI, One is **Price** and **ExtrasPrice**.

Item Price and other fields will be saved in Item table.
And ExtrasPrice field needs to insert new entry in ItemExtras table if it is there.

What is the best way to create and request end points (CRUD)?

1. Create two separate end points for Item and ItemExtras
2. Create two separate end points for both but handles ItemExtras CRUD(By calling endpoints) from Item end points.
3. Create endpoints which handles both tables CRUD.

Comment: Do you want to expose ItemExtras to be accessed publicly or from your frontend?

Comment: Depends on requirement, Currently there is no requirement. So ask for Best way.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it depends on the domain logic and requirements. Since there are none and you're asking for the best way, here's my opinion about this:

Since the ItemExtras is a child entity of Item, you can never create or update an ItemExtras without having an Item first. What would be the meaning of an ItemExtras record in your database if there's no parent Item record for it?

I would go for a single endpoint, to create the entire Item object, including the ItemExtras. Something like this:

```
POST /api/items
```

You can create two endpoints to give the clients of your API the flexibility, but making two API calls is probably something you want to avoid. What if the API call for creating an ItemExtras succeeds, but the API call for creating an Item fails? Then you have "incorrect" data in your database, as mentioned before (there's no use of having an ItemExtras without having an Item).
Calling another endpoint from your own API (your option two) feels weird to me. Why have multiple endpoints if they're going to call each other anyway?

Should you ever need to update an ItemExtras, without updating any details about the Item itself, you can create an endpoint like this:

```
PUT /api/items/{itemId}/ItemExtras/{itemExtrasId}
```

This also forces the clients of your API to have an Item record, before they can update an ItemExtras record.

Hope this makes sense.